# Currying in Typed Racket

Tags: racket, currying, typed-racket

In regular Racket, `((curry * 2) 3)` works as expected, with `6` as a result.

However, in Typed Racket:

```
> ((curry * 2) 3)
; readline-input:3:0: Type Checker: could not apply function;
;  wrong number of arguments provided
;   expected: 0
;   given: 1
;   in: ((curry * 2) 3)
; [,bt for context]
```

Why?

Comment: (deleted because this was more of an answer, so I copied the text to an answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with the fact that * can take only one argument, so when you curry it with a parameter, it is returning a procedure that takes no additional arguments. Type `(curry * 2)` at the command line in typed/racket and observe the result: `(-> Number)`.

Note that there is only a return type and no parameter. I don't see a way around this in typed racket, but I hope that at least explains why it is happening. You should be safe to use currying with more complex procedures as long as they do not have an option to take only one parameter.

Comment: Indeed, when I `(define mult *)` with `(: mult : (-> Number Number Number))` It works fine. That's weird though; is currying impossible for multi-arity procedures, in Typed Racket?

Comment: I don't know enough about Typed Racket to answer your comment but I can provide a shorthand for your workaround: `((curry (ann * (-> Number Number Number)) 2) 3)`. See [ann](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=inst#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._ann%29%29).